# How to use CFFI with multiple header files

Tags: python, c, python-cffi

I have C header file with some functions and structure definitions. But that C header file includes multiple other c header files. Some of my structures that I need use other structures from other header files as their members. How can I use CFFI API mode without copying and pasting every header file into cdef and set_source?